# How to cloning data buffers (bio_vec-s) from original BIO to a new bio_vec set?

Tags: linux-device-driver

I need to clone data, which has been carried by the bio in the bi_io_vec. I looking for a correct sequence of calls to performs:

1. new bio_vec allocation
2. copy original bio_vec-s to a new
3. deallocation  of bio_vec-s area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static int __dua_bvec_clone (
        struct bio  *src,
        IOB_ARGS    *iob_args
            )
{
int status;
unsigned nr_vecs = src->bi_vcnt;
struct bio *dst;
struct bvec_iter src_iter, dst_iter;
struct bio_vec  src_bv, dst_bv;
void *src_p, *dst_p;
unsigned bv_len;

    $TRACE("Start cloning ...");

    $SHOW_PTR(src);
    $SHOW_INT(src->bi_vcnt);

    /* Allocate a memory for a new 'bio' structure */
    if ( !(dst = bio_clone_bioset(src, GFP_KERNEL, src->bi_pool /*NULL*/)) )
        {
        printk(KERN_ERR  __MODULE__ ": bio_clone_bioset() -> NULL\n");

        return  -ENOMEM;
        }

    if ( status = bio_alloc_pages(dst , GFP_KERNEL))
        {
        printk(KERN_ERR  __MODULE__ ": bio_alloc_pages() -> %d\n", status);

        return  status;
        }

    /* Copy data from source bio_vec-s to a new bio_vec-s set */
    src_iter = src->bi_iter;
    dst_iter = dst->bi_iter;

    while( nr_vecs--)
        {
        src_bv = bio_iter_iovec(src, src_iter);
        dst_bv = bio_iter_iovec(dst, dst_iter);

        bv_len = min(src_bv.bv_len, dst_bv.bv_len);

        src_p = kmap_atomic(src_bv.bv_page);
        dst_p = kmap_atomic(dst_bv.bv_page);

        $SHOW_PTR(src_p);
        $SHOW_PTR(dst_p);

        memcpy(dst_p + dst_bv.bv_offset, src_p + src_bv.bv_offset, bv_len);

        kunmap_atomic(dst_p);
        kunmap_atomic(src_p);

        bio_advance_iter(src, &src_iter, bv_len);
        bio_advance_iter(dst, &dst_iter, bv_len);
        }



    iob_args->bi_io_vec = src->bi_io_vec;
    src->bi_io_vec = dst->bi_io_vec;

    iob_args->bio = dst;

    $TRACE("Cloned.");

    return  0;
}
```

Comment: This is not work in really because after cloning - new BIO share BVECs from original BIO. So, it need to allocate new BVECs has been attached to the cloned BIO and copyng contains of buffers from old BVECs to new.